# Test a deck of Cards

Tags: java, testing, mockito

Trying to learn how to test in Java and think I have been at it for to long now because it feels like the more I trial and error the less I understand. I can't figure out how to test the Deck by filling it up with mocked cards? I wanna be able to test that the first card in the deck actually is a two of hearts before the deck gets shuffled or maybe compare it a whole list of cards just made for the test, but right now it stands totally still. Anyone who got any tips for testing a Deck with cards in a good way?

***Card.java***

```
package model;

public class Card {

    public enum Value {
        Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Knight, Queen, King, Ace
    }

    public enum Suite {
        Hearts, Spades, Diamonds, Clubs
    }

    private Value value;
    private Suite suite;

    public Card(Value value, Suite suite) {
        if(value == null || suite == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Argument can't be null");
        }

        this.value = value;
        this.suite = suite;
    }

    public Object getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public Object getSuite() {
        return this.suite;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return value + " of " + suite;
    }
}
```

***Deck.java***

```
package model;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Deck {

    private ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList<Card>();  
    private CardFactory CF = new CardFactory();

    public Deck(){
        init();
    }

    public void init() {        
        for (int i=0; i<13; i++){    
            for (int j=0; j<4; j++){
                //card = cardFactory.createCard(Card.Value.values()[i], Card.Suite.values()[j]);
                this.cards.add(CF.createCard(Card.Value.values()[i], Card.Suite.values()[j]));          
            }
        }
    }

    public Card getCard() {     
        return cards.remove(0);
    }

    public int cardsLeft() {        
        return cards.size();        
    }   

    public Card getLastCard() {
        return cards.remove(cards.size()-1);
    }
}
```

***CardFactory.java***

```
package model;

public class CardFactory {

    public Card createCard(Card.Value value, Card.Suite suite){
        return new Card(value, suite);
    }

}
```

***DeckTest.java***

```
package model;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

public class DeckTest {

    @Mock private ArrayList<Card> cards;
    @Mock private Card card;
    @Mock private CardFactory CF;

    @InjectMocks private Deck sut;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        initMocks(this);
    }   

    @Test   
    public void DeckContains52Cards() {                     
        sut.init();     
        verify(cards, Mockito.times(52)).add(Mockito.any());
    }

    @Test   
    public void getCardIsCalled() {     
        sut.getCard();
        verify(cards).remove(0);        
    }

    @Test   
    public void cardsLeftIsCalled() {       
        sut.cardsLeft();        
        verify(cards).size();       
    }

    @Test   
    public void getLastCardIsCalled() {     
        sut.getLastCard();
        verify(cards).size();       
    }   
}
```

Comment: The `CardFactory` has no freedom at all to define which cards to create. This is not how factories work.

Ideally you would create an abstract or interface `CardFactory`, and would inject a concrete implementation `PokerDeckCardFactory` which would generate all the cards in one go... You can inject the CardFactory by passing it as a parameter in the constructor.

Comment: Ok mostly did the factory to move the creation of new cards out from the deck to be able to mock the factory and return mocked cards instead of having use the "real" cards (which i haven't got working the way i thought). But I will take a look at the factory and return a whole deck instead. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are getting it wrong.

First you separate the dependencies. The `CardFactory` needs freedom to produce the cards it requires:

```
public interface (or abstract class) CardFactory {
    public List<Card> getCards();
}
```

and

```
public class PokerCardFactory implements CardFactory {
  public List<Card> getCards() {
    ArrayList<Card> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0; i<13; i++){    
      for (int j=0; j<4; j++){
        result.add(this.createCard(Card.Value.values()[i], Card.Suite.values()[j]));          
      }
    }
    return result;
  }

  private Card createCard(Value value, Suite suite) {
     ...
  }
}
```

then you inject the dependency (for example in the constructor) and use it to generate the cards.

You want to test `Deck` and not `PokerCardFactory`, so you inject a simpler `CardFactory` to simplify testing. Here comes mockito, allowing you to create such a factory writting way less code.

```
@Mock private CardFactory cardFactory
@Test
public void numberOfCards {
  ArrayList<Card> cards = new ArrayList();
  cards.add(new Card(Value.Two, Suite.Hearts));
  cards.add(new Card(Value.Three, Suite.Aces));
  when(cardFactory.getCards()).thenReturn(cards); // Now we have a CardFactory that will produce a deck with just two cards.
  Deck deck = new Deck(cardFactory); // Dependency injection.
  assertEquals("The number of cards does not match", 2, deck.getNumberOfCards()); // You have tested `getNumberOfCards`.
}
```

Comment: I did not have any mockito examples nearby so there may be some syntax error, but this is the idea.

Comment: This way isn't the DeckTest Dependent on the Card class? For example if I were to break the Card class couldn't that also break the DeckTest? Could I solve that by mocking the cards? I Thanks by the way!

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you want to test, that the first card on your deck is a hearts of two, your test should look something like this:

```
Deck deck = new Deck();

Card firstCard = deck.getCard();

assertCard(firstCard, Value.Two, Suite.Hearts) // orwhatever
```

No needs for mocks yet, huh? ;)

But that is basically wrong, because first of all, the second card could be the ace of spaces and second, you do not want to test 'getCard', you want to *verify*, that the Deck calls the CardFactory in the correct order. You've used verify anyway, so no need to explain.
But I don't like this test anyway because I don't see any value per se. As long as the shuffle works, it's 52 cards and no card duplicated, this test is obsolete, but still good for learning purpose, I guess.

Since I can't comment, @SJuan76's answer: This test doesn't test anything. I can switch the cards, I can remove the first entry and add the second to its place or I can even add two null's to a newly created list and the test still passes. The only thing that it should test after your refactoring is the verification, that cardFactory.getCards is called, because that's the only thing it does and from a test perspective, must do.

Comment: Thanks for the input, any suggestions on what to test on a deck. Doing tests on my own and not only testing something the teacher told me to test, been a really frustrating couple of days ;)

Comment: Well... test driven development works like this: Write failing test, implement (make it pass), refactor (see Kent Beck's or Freeman/Pryce's book on this).

Comment: (I hate it, that enter submits the comment). For instance getCard is a good example. _given_ a deck with a List of cards, _when_ i call getCard _then_ I expect, that the first Card of the deck is removed and return, and the amounf of cards in the deck is one less. (Hint: Always write your test in the give-when-then pattern, also do the formatting like this, it improves the readability of the test and makes its intention more clear)